# Unexpected int at end of statement

Tags: go, struct, slice

I'm struggling a bit with this piece of Go code. I have been searching all over the place, but can't understand what is wrong about it.

Error message is: syntax error: unexpected int at end of statement

for that line near the bottom: `func (TOHLCV TOHLCVs) Len() int {`

I also have this error message for the second to the last line of code:

```
syntax error: non-declaration statement outside function body
```

In case the 2 errors are related

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "strconv"

    //from https://github.com/pplcc/plotext/
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/360EntSecGroup-Skylar/excelize"
    "github.com/pplcc/plotext/custplotter"
    "gonum.org/v1/plot"
    "github.com/pplcc/plotext"
    "gonum.org/v1/plot/vg/vgimg"
    "gonum.org/v1/plot/vg/draw"
)

    // Len implements the Len method of the TOHLCVer interface.
    func (TOHLCV TOHLCVs) Len() int {
        return len(TOHLCV)

func main() {

//read excel file******************************************
    xlsx, err := excelize.OpenFile("/media/Snaps/test snaps.xlsm")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    //read all rows into df
    df := xlsx.GetRows("ticker_2")

    type TOHLCVer interface {
        // Len returns the number of time, open, high, low, close, volume tuples.
        Len() int

        // TOHLCV returns an time, open, high, low, close, volume tuple.
        TOHLCV(int) (float64, float64, float64, float64, float64, float64)
    }

    type TOHLCVs []struct{ T, O, H, L, C, V float64 }

    // Len implements the Len method of the TOHLCVer interface.
    func (TOHLCV TOHLCVs) Len() int {
        return len(TOHLCV)
    }

    df3 := make(TOHLCVs, 60) // create slice for 60 rows
    idx := 0
```

this code is adapted from:
https://github.com/pplcc/plotext/blob/master/custplotter/tohlcv.go

Comment: You cannot declare methods inside a function, methods can be declared only at the package level.

Comment: Hey @Hugues , same bit of code again it seems :) gotour will really get you through what you can and can't do in go pretty quickly, you might enjoy giving it a go. Otherwise, is this bit of code inside another function?

Comment: @mkopriva thanks. you refer to the second error message ?

Comment: @Hugues to both

Comment: @aec indeed i'm struggling to put it together, but i think i'm close. By gotour, you mean? : https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1

Comment: yes, I meant tour.golang.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So based on answer of @Tyler Bui-Palsulich  and @aec my code now looks like below, and no more error messages :-), thanks all !

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    "strconv"

    //from https://github.com/pplcc/plotext/
    "log"
    "os"

    "github.com/360EntSecGroup-Skylar/excelize"
    "github.com/pplcc/plotext/custplotter"
    //"github.com/pplcc/plotext/examples"
    "gonum.org/v1/plot"
    "github.com/pplcc/plotext"
    "gonum.org/v1/plot/vg/vgimg"
    "gonum.org/v1/plot/vg/draw"
)

// Len implements the Len method of the TOHLCVer interface.
//func (TOHLCV TOHLCVs) Len() int {
//    return len(TOHLCV)
//}

type TOHLCVer interface {
    // Len returns the number of time, open, high, low, close, volume tuples.
    Len() int

    // TOHLCV returns an time, open, high, low, close, volume tuple.
    TOHLCV(int) (float64, float64, float64, float64, float64, float64)
}

type TOHLCVs []struct{ T, O, H, L, C, V float64 }

// Len implements the Len method of the TOHLCVer interface.
func (TOHLCV TOHLCVs) Len() int {
    return len(TOHLCV)
}

// TOHLCV implements the TOHLCV method of the TOHLCVer interface.
func (TOHLCV TOHLCVs) TOHLCV(i int) (float64, float64, float64, float64, float64, float64) {
    return TOHLCV[i].T, TOHLCV[i].O, TOHLCV[i].H, TOHLCV[i].L, TOHLCV[i].C, TOHLCV[i].V
}

func main() {

start := time.Now()

//create data for each chart****************************************************
//******************************************************************************

    //read excel file******************************************
    xlsx, err := excelize.OpenFile("/media/hugues/M.2 windows/Hugues/Snaps/test snaps.xlsm")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    //read all rows into df
    df := xlsx.GetRows("ticker_2")


    df3 := make(TOHLCVs, 60) // create slice for 60 rows
    idx := 0
    for _, row := range df[1:61] { // read 60 rows
    df3[idx].T, err = strconv.ParseFloat(row[28], 64)
    df3[idx].O, err = strconv.ParseFloat(row[29], 64)
    df3[idx].H, err = strconv.ParseFloat(row[30], 64)
    df3[idx].L, err = strconv.ParseFloat(row[31], 64)
    df3[idx].C, err = strconv.ParseFloat(row[32], 64)
    df3[idx].V, err = strconv.ParseFloat(row[33], 64)
    idx++
    }
```

Comment: Well you do seem to be missing the TOHLCV method. You need to do the same thing you did with the `Len()`. See my example in the previous question of yours and how I implemented it.

Comment: @aec, you were right, I've added it now to the code above and all error messages gone, I've got the data formatted properly for the next stage of my code. P.S.: i cannot mark this code as an answer for some reason, can someone do it for me ?

Comment: You'll have the privilege (ha ha) to answer your own questions when you earn more points. You can leave this question as is and mark it answered later if you like, or you can just accept Tyler's response

Answer (score 2):

Function declarations need to be moved out of other functions, Like [this](https://play.golang.org/p/5OlgFCVoHZh):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "github.com/360EntSecGroup-Skylar/excelize"
)

type TOHLCVer interface {
    // Len returns the number of time, open, high, low, close, volume tuples.
    Len() int

    // TOHLCV returns an time, open, high, low, close, volume tuple.
    TOHLCV(int) (float64, float64, float64, float64, float64, float64)
}

type TOHLCVs []struct{ T, O, H, L, C, V float64 }

// Len implements the Len method of the TOHLCVer interface.
func (TOHLCV TOHLCVs) Len() int {
    return len(TOHLCV)
}

func main() {
    //read excel file******************************************
    xlsx, err := excelize.OpenFile("/media/Snaps/test snaps.xlsm")
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }

    //read all rows into df
    df := xlsx.GetRows("ticker_2")

    df3 := make(TOHLCVs, 60) // create slice for 60 rows
    idx := 0
}
```

Type declarations can be inside of a function. But, in this case, it makes more sense for them to be outside. There are some situations where it's helpful to declare a function inside another function:

- Passing a function as an argument: https://play.golang.org/p/4NgeUvsexto
- Assigning an anonymous function to a variable: https://play.golang.org/p/r1DF9_iP0-k

(I'm not sure about the exact logic you're looking for - the above code doesn't do anything yet. I'll also caution against creating an interface unless you needed it.)

Comment: sorry, i've pasted the top part of my code now, i was too fast. Is your answer still valid ? (i've skipped the bottom part for now)

Comment: I updated the answer to incorporate your updated code. The function declarations need to be moved outside of the main function. I included a note about how you can create anonymous functions.